# iis8.5 Not Found page, SNI and Host Headers. Refuse Connection Possible

Tags: http, https, http-status-code-404, iis-8.5

I am using IIS8.5 to host a few internal and external sub domains. Everything is working prefect but I have one thing I would like to change and I have no idea where to start.

I have set each site http and https bindings and I require SNI since I have multiple sub domains and no external trusted wildcard cert.

When attempting to visit the external (http or https) IP address of my server I get a simple version of a 404 Not found page. (Not the normal iis 404 page)

[Not Found Picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B94OvyHliPFVaFhUelRQVjh3TVk/view?usp=sharing)

When someone visits the external IP of my server I would like both http and https to refuse the connection / provide web page not available. I do not know how to stop serving the Not Found error and just refuse the connection and if that is not possible where is this simple 404 Not Found page located so I can modify it in some way.

Any help would be great. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the page comes from IIS? Check the Response header for the server field in your browser's F12 tools.

Comment: There is no server field that I can find. I am pretty sure it is IIS because if I go to the HTTPS IP it will show the same Not Found page and serve my internal SSL cert. Of course it will be untrusted as the host name does not match I am typing in an IP